# SQL select with three levels of foreign key indirection

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have the following tables:

```
component_cmp      [id], id_cty_cmp*, ...
comp_structure_cst [id_cty_cst*, property_cst], validation_cst, ...
comp_value_cva     [id_cmp_cva*, property_cva], value_cva, ...
comp_type_cty      [id_cty], ...
```

Brackets are primary keys, * foreign key (roughly)

`ComponentType` owns many `Component`s, each `Component` has many `CompValue`s.
Each `CompType` owns many `CompStructure`, which are kind of "template" for `CompValue`s.

The schema is a bit messy, yeah.

Something like this (rough ER diagram):

```
CompTypeCty -+-----< CompStructureCst - - - - indirect -
|                                                       |
+-------< ComponentCmp -+----< CompValueCva  - - - - - -
```

**I want to select** rows from `CompValueCva`, that have `validation_cst` equal to given value. It's a really nasty indirection, but I believe it can be done in SQL.

So far I've came up with this but it is wrong (gives me truckload of incorrect duplicate entries):

```
select cva.*
from comp_value_cva cva
left join component_cmp cmp on cva.id_cmp_cva = cmp.id
left join comp_structure_cst cst on cst.id_cty_cst = cmp.id_cty_cmp
where cst.validation_cst = 'celsius';
```

(it's SQLite syntax but MySQL syntax will work for me too)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was being stupid and did not realize I have "composite foreign indirect keys".

The correct query is:

```
select cva.*
from comp_value_cva cva
left join component_cmp cmp on cva.id_cmp_cva = cmp.id
left join comp_structure_cst cst on (cst.id_cty_cst = cmp.id_cty_cmp AND cst.property_cst = cva.property_cva)
where cst.validation_cst = 'celsius'
```

Comment: You don't actually need `LEFT` joins for this. (or at least you wouldn't in mysql)

Comment: Well go ahead and show me a faster / nicer way, I can still accept it ^^

Comment: I'm not sure if it would  be any faster, because the internal query optimizer might be doing it already, but `INNER JOIN` might help if the query optimizer is being dumb. 

Also, I can't know for sure without knowing more about your data structure, but I am guessing the `cmp` table might not even be needed in this query since it looks like you have a direct link to `cva` in the `cst` one. But yeah, I could be underestimating the difficulty in describing your relations succinctly.